# cannot borrow `rdr` as mutable more than once at a time [when using library from cargo]

Tags: rust

Running the below code:

```
extern crate csv;  // csv = "1.0.0-beta.5"

use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let file_path = "file.csv";
    let file = File::open(file_path).unwrap();

    let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(true)
        .from_reader(file);
    let headers = rdr.headers().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", headers);

    //println!("{:?}", rdr.headers().unwrap());

    for result in rdr.records() {
        let record = result.unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", record);
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `rdr` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:17:19
   |
12 |     let headers = rdr.headers().unwrap();
   |                   --- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
17 |     for result in rdr.records() {
   |                   ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
21 | }
   | - first borrow ends here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

If I change these lines:

```
let headers = rdr.headers().unwrap();
println!("{:?}", headers);

//println!("{:?}", rdr.headers().unwrap());
```

to the below the code works:

```
//let headers = rdr.headers().unwrap();
//println!("{:?}", headers);

println!("{:?}", rdr.headers().unwrap());
```

Similarly if I `clone` the headers it also works:

```
let headers = rdr.headers().unwrap().clone();
println!("{:?}", headers);
```

I read a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281155/cannot-borrow-x-as-mutable-more-than-once-at-a-time) however that question was about a function that the user wrote themselves whereas this use case is where a function was provided by a library.

How should such errors be dealt with and what exactly is happening to cause this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `headers` [signature](https://docs.rs/csv/1.0.0-beta.5/csv/struct.Reader.html#method.headers), it is:

```
fn headers(&mut self) -> Result<&StringRecord>;
```

So `headers()` mutably borrows `ReaderBuilder`'s instance.
Same for [`records()`](https://docs.rs/csv/1.0.0-beta.5/csv/struct.Reader.html#method.records):

```
fn records(&mut self) -> StringRecordsIter<R>;
```

Both of the return types of these functions contains mutable reference(s) to the underlying `ReaderBuilder` instance.

As per rust's [borrow rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references), you cannot have multiple mutable references to the *same* object living at the *same* time.

**Possible mitigation**: Use `headers()` in a separate scope. Thus, the references are dropped, before `records()` is called.

```
let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
    .has_headers(true)
    .from_reader(file);
{
   let headers = rdr.headers().unwrap();
   println!("{:?}", headers);
   // `headers` is dropped here.
}

for result in rdr.records() {
    let record = result.unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", record);
}
```

The error does not occur when you `clone` because another brand new object is created and allocated on cloning. You do not have multiple mutable references anymore.

Same, when you use `println!("{:?}", rdr.headers().unwrap());`, the value returned by `headers()` is dropped immediately, so the borrow checker does not complain about multiple mutable references.

Whether the functions are provided by a library or created by a user is irrelevant. The only thing that matters is the functions' signatures.