# mutable more than once at a time

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

In this following code [playgroud](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=61bde196bcd1c55b7370b2e47eae7291).

The first solution doesn't compile:

```
let c = manager.add_currency(Currency {
  name: "EUR".to_string(),
});

let _i = manager.add_instrument(Instrument {
  name: "RRR".to_string(),
  currency: c.clone(),
});
```

with this error msg

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `manager` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:59:18
   |
55 |           let c = manager.add_currency(Currency {
   |  _________________-
56 | |             name: "EUR".to_string(),
57 | |         });
   | |__________- first mutable borrow occurs here
58 | 
59 |           let _i = manager.add_instrument(Instrument {
   |  __________________^
60 | |             name: "RRR".to_string(),
61 | |             currency: c.clone(),
   | |                       --------- first borrow later used here
62 | |         });
   | |__________^ second mutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281155/cannot-borrow-x-as-mutable-more-than-once-at-a-time), i understand "c" is an reference on Rc and borrow/mutable manager because add_currency is mutable.
right ?

so add_instrument want to borrow/mutable manager, there is an error

But if i update my code :

```
manager.add_currency(Currency {
  name: "EUR".to_string(),
});

let c = manager.get_last_currency();
let _i = manager.add_instrument(Instrument {
  name: "RRR".to_string(),
  currency: c.clone(),
});
```

compile without error
it is same situation c is an borrow/not mutable from manager
and it is impossible with a variable to borrow as mutable and un mutable in same time.

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you use `Rc` all over the place, you should not try to keep references on them.
In my opinion this usage of `Rc` is very Java-ish (no explicit ownership, everyone shares the ownership of everything) and is not exactly if spirit of Rust (precise ownership model, borrowing...).

If you want to keep these `Rc`s, I suggest you `clone()` them when they are returned, so that we don't have to keep borrowing the structure containing them.
They are designed with this usage in mind: you clone them (it's cheap, relative to cloning the data they refer to) in order to share ownership.

If you actually could keep references to these `Rc`s at the call site (thus keep borrowing `Manager`), then this would mean that you probably could get rid of these `Rc`s.

Of course, you don't have to clone again the obtained `Rc`s at the call site.

```rust
    fn add_currency(
        &mut self,
        c: Currency,
    ) -> Rc<Currency> {
        let rc = Rc::new(c);
        self.currencies.push(rc.clone());
        rc // no reference here, but a clone of the stored Rc
    }

    fn get_last_currency(&self) -> Rc<Currency> {
        self.currencies.last().unwrap().clone() // no reference here, but a clone of the stored Rc
    }

    fn add_instrument(
        &mut self,
        i: Instrument,
    ) -> Rc<Instrument> {
        let rc = Rc::new(i);
        self.instruments.push(rc.clone());
        rc // no reference here, but a clone of the stored Rc
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the second (working) version is an instance of two-phased borrows. [rust-lang/rust#56254](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/56254) for reference. Which was recently changed from being a future incompatibility lint to being an allowed code pattern. [rust-lang/rust#96268](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/96268/) for reference.

As such this is a special exception to the usual rules.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `self` argument from the associated `add_currency()` function and returning `Rc<Currency>`:

```
fn add_currency(currencies: &mut Vec<Rc<Currency>>, c: Currency) -> Rc<Currency> {
    currencies.push(Rc::new(c));
    currencies.last().cloned().unwrap()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c3389a8acc1ea457e837d713c27313a9)